# Count the number sequence same for same item but restart to 1 when enter new month

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I want to get sequential number as in column AB as image attached below:

[image: Expected outcome in column AB]

Sequence number in column AB would be my expected outcome but what I can do is just overall sequence number as in column AA. This is my formula in column AA: `=IF(COUNTIF(Y$2:Y4,Y4)=1,MAX(AA$1:AA3)+1,VLOOKUP(Y4,Y$1:AA3,3,0))`

Cannot think anymore how to restart sequence number to 1 when its a different month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=query({unique(filter(Y$2:Y,Z$2:Z=Z2)),sequence(rows(unique(filter(Y$2:Y,Z$2:Z=Z2))))},"select Col2 where Col1 = '"&Y2&"'")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, its working wonder! But anyhow, you know how to convert to arrayformula?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(Y2:Y&Z2:Z="",,COUNTIF(Y2:Y&Z2:Z, Y2:Y&Z2:Z)))
```

Answer (score 0):

"how to restart sequence number to 1 when its a different month."
`=if(month(Z3)=month(Z2),<continuation>,1)`
That is assuming that in Z you have numbers formatted as mmm-dd rather than text.
If it's text then `=if(left(Z3,3))=left(Z2,3)),<continuation>,1)`